# Connect sqlite with HTML5 on server

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

How can I connect an HTML5 web application to a sqlite database which is on server side?

Comment: With a tutorial ? But one way would be ajax to server side scripts.

Comment: can u please explain  in breif how can i acheive that as i dont know much about ajax?

Comment: DON below has provided some reading material ! I suggest you start there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a server-side language such as php (or any other server-side language that has support for sqlite databases). A client-side application can't access anything on the server other than information exposed as http services (a web page or json web service for example). Your html5 application can use ajax to make the http request to the server-side script which actually makes the sqlite database queries and returns the information to your application.  Using a good client-side library like jquery can make the ajax calls quite easy:

```
$.getJSON("path/to/server-side-script.php", function(dataReturned){ 
  alert(dataReturned);
};
```

The code above is just an example - it may not be exactly correct, but you should get the idea. I won't put an example of what the server-side script would do to retrieve the data from sqlite and return it as JSON (or whatever data format you like) - they are easily found with a quick google/bing search.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the blogs which explains connecting sqllite with html5

[SQL Lite Class for HTML5 Database](http://blog.heldes.com/html5/sqlite-class-for-html5-database/)

[Store Data in HTML5 Sql Lite](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html)

Comment: i think these links explain about database stored on client browser and that is not the requirement.I wanted to be connect to database which is on sever side and the HTML% application itself on server side.can u please guide me on that?

Comment: @rajG `HTML` always execute on client side. Can you be more specific? What are your requirements ?

Comment: i think these links explain about database stored on client browser and that is not the requirement.I wanted to be connect to database which is on sever side and the HTML% application itself on server side.can u please guide me on that?

Comment: my HTML% web application will be on server and i want connect the sqlite database which is on server itself.......that is the scenario

Comment: @rajG Even `HTML` is on server, it will be executed at client only (ie) on browser. Are you using any server side language ?

Comment: Is node js would be helpful for me on that side?

Comment: i heard these days about node js.Would it be helpful for me on my issue?

Comment: Node.js is just another server-side language you could use.  You are confusing the fact that your html FILE is stored on your server, but it does not _execute_ on the server.  It executes (renders, runs javascript, etc) in the browser.  All the server does with an html file is send the file to your browser.  In order to run code on the server you need a server-side language, such as .net, php, node.js (javascript), or any other language that has sqlite database libraries available.

Comment: thanks @AllanNienhuis i got it.I will try with node js to do that work